# Objective-C retain cycle between 2 objects

Tags: objective-c, retain-cycle, strong-reference-cycle

Here is the code:

```
TestA *ta = [[TestA alloc] init];
TestB *tb = [[TestB alloc] init];  

ta.b = tb;
tb.a = ta;
```

I tried to set `ta = nil` or `tb = nil`. It didn't work but `ta.b = nil` worked. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to set `ta = nil` or `tb = nil`, it didn't work,

This is because, as you point out, you have a "strong reference cycle" (formerly known as a "retain cycle"). This is the very definition of a strong reference cycle.

The `TestA` object that `ta` referenced still has a reference to the `TestB` object that `tb` originally referenced. Likewise, the `TestB` object that `tb` referenced still is keeping a strong reference to that `TestA` instance that `ta` originally referenced. So even after you set both the `ta` and `tb` pointers to `nil`, the actual objects that they originally pointed to are still keeping references to each other. Hence the cycle.

The key observation is that when you set `ta` and `tb` pointers to `nil`, it doesn’t do anything but removing your references to these `TestA` and `TestB` instances. But as long as there's something else maintaining a strong reference to these instances (in this case, they're maintaining strong references to each other), they won't be deallocated. We refer to the memory associated with those two objects as having been “abandoned”, i.e., you don’t have any references to them even though they’re not deallocated because they’re tied up in their mutual strong reference cycle.

The "Debug Memory Graph" feature, [image], is really useful in visualizing this. So after I set `ta` and `tb` to both be `nil`, I looked at the memory graph and it shows that my `ViewController` no longer had reference to these two objects, but they're still both referencing each other:

[image]

> but `ta.b = nil` worked. why??!!

This works (assuming you did this before setting `ta` to `nil`) because it breaks the strong reference cycle. When you set `ta.b` to `nil`, the `TestB` object no longer has any strong references and it can be deallocated. And, once that `TestB` instance is deallocated, it will remove its reference to that `TestA` instance, so that `TestA` instance will also be deallocated because the last strong reference to it will have been removed.

---

Perhaps needless to say, but the way you prevent this problem is to make one of the properties `weak`. For example, if `TestA` is the logical “parent” object, you’d probably make the `b` property in `TestA` a `strong` property, but make the `a` property in `TestB` a `weak` property. This resolves the strong reference cycle and eliminates this problem entirely.